# Qt Store SQLITE Row Data In QStringList

Tags: sql, qt, sqlite

I would like to store the entirety of a row (customer name, row 1) in my sql table (Customers) in a QStringList, but i'm unsure how i would go about doing this, all help is much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: So, do you want save all rows? or just first? This stringlist should be only with customer name. Clarify please.

Comment: I would like to save all the data in the row into a stringlist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use `QVector<QStringList>`. In this case it will be more easier to work with it. For example:

```
QSqlQuery query("SELECT * FROM newTab");
QVector<QStringList> lst;
while (query.next())
{
    QSqlRecord record = query.record();
    QStringList tmp;
    for(int i=0; i < record.count(); i++)
    {
        tmp << record.value(i).toString();
    }
    lst.append(tmp);
}
foreach (const QStringList &var, lst) {
    qDebug() << var;
}
```

Output with `QVector` will very similar to table. Each iteration means each row with all fields inside it(`QStringList`):

```
("0", "Name1", "5000") 
("1", "Name2", "1000") 
("2", "Name3", "2000")
```

Comment: Is there any way i use only one row not select *

Comment: @Root0x query.next() iterates throw every row, so if you want only first row, just don't use query.next(). In this case you also don't need QVector. If you want get data from one column then you can set this column in your query or by setting some number to value(num)